# cmake command line - pass var dependent on the build type

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to create a cmake build with multiple configurations: Debug/Release.
I am using msvc, so I can call cmake once to configure both Debug and Release projects.

My problem:

- I have a custom variable that I want to pass to cmake via command line
- and that variable depends! on the build type!

e.g.

- `cmake -DMYVAR=alfa //if the build type is Debug`
- `cmake -DMYVAR=beta //if the build type is Release`

The thing is: I was hoping to call cmake once and to use a conditional.
(I do not want to call cmake twice, with separate values)

My option is not part of `CXX_FLAGS`. For those, I could have used `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` / `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

So my questions:

1. is there a way in cmake to set a variable, in the command line, based on the 'current' build type that is internally used when cmake runs?
2. If the answer for #1 is "no", I guess I have to call cmake twice. Is that the way to go?
   (I do not want to modify the `CMakeLists` file)

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way in cmake to set a variable, in the command line, based on the 'current' build type that is internally used when cmake runs?

Generally, no.

First of all, in multi-configuration generators (like MSVC) there is **no** "*current build type*". When process `CMakeLists.txt`, CMake doesn't have build type set, neither publicly nor internally. Only when processing of `CMakeLists.txt` is completed, CMake generates parameters for every configuration (build type).

Build-type dependent things are normally set with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) - values, which conditionally depend from the configuration or configuration-specific settings.
But only a selected set of commands (and selected set of their parameters) could use generator expressions.

So, if the project uses a variable in a context, when generator expressions are forbidden, then you can set this variable to configuration-specific value neither inside `CMakeLists.txt` nor from the command line. E.g. if a variable is used in `if()` command, then generator expressions cannot be used for specifying a value for the variable.

Comment: thanks, I was expecting that :(.  I was just hoping that there is a cmake convention somewhere for (user specified) build-type dependent variables similar to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG /CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE, but I guess there is none, thanks!